# CMS umbraco - xsl descendant

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have a page with a folder and links inside

```
-FirstPage
  +folder
  -page
  -page
  -folder
    -link1
    -link2
    -link3
  -page
```

I want to reach the link1,link2,link3 in the tree. My current page is FirstPage.
How do I do that??
This is the xsl i wrote and he give me the first link in the top folder

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/descendant-or-self::* [@isDoc][@level=2]">
<xsl:if test="count(current()/descendant::* [@isDoc]) &gt; 0">
<xsl:variable name="descendantPage" select="current()/descendant::* [@isDoc]"/>   
<xsl:value-of select="$descendantPage/text"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you for your help.

edit:new xsl I use...

```
<xsl:variable name="fId" select="number(1395)" />
<xsl:variable name="linksFolder" select="$currentPage/descendant-or-self::* [@isDoc][@level=2][@id='$fId']">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="$linksFolder/* [@isDoc]">
    <xsl:value-of select="./text">
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

How can i avoid to use a output (like the id of the folder) to get the folder i want to?
Thanks for your help...

Comment: It depends, is there only ever one folder of links, or can there potentially be many folders of links?

Comment: Hi Tim,
For the FirstPage this will be the only folder of links. But said that a page inside the tree can have a different folder of links.
I will be glad to learn the two methods you are thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of helpful tips & tricks in the Umbraco WikiBook online (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Various_useful_XSLT_methods_in_Umbraco).  You can use the doc type of the folder node to find the links (instead of the id).

For example looping round all nodes of a certain doc type (linkFolderDocType):

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root//node [@nodeTypeAlias='linkFolderDocType']">
  <xsl:value-of select="./text">
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way in my xslt version **./node** doesn't work i need to write **./* [@isDoc]**. And docType will not help because i Have more than one folder with the doctype at this level of the tree.